# How to add a JavaScript tag attribute in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs

What is the proper way to add a js tag attribute in Magento 2?

This is needed for example for Cloudflare Rocket loader to ignore a certain script.

```
<script data-cfasync="true" type="text/javascript" src="~~">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script data-cfasync="false" src="/javascript.js"></script>
```

Try this